# Calculate elapsed time using datatime data in R

Tags: r, datetime

I'm working on a clinical dataset in which samples were taken from subjects after taking a dose of a medication. The datetime column for samples and doses were provided in the following format directly from the clinical data base.

The intended output is to create a column for the elapsed time after dose (i.e.: Sample.Time - Dose.Time). The output can be in minutes or hours. N.B: we need to use both date and time because sampling can occur is a different date than dosing.

```
Sample.Time         Dose.Time
2019-06-07T08:23    2019-06-07T07:53
2019-06-07T08:53    2019-06-07T07:53
2019-06-07T09:23    2019-06-07T07:53
2019-06-07T09:53    2019-06-07T07:53
2019-06-07T10:23    2019-06-07T07:53
2019-06-07T10:53    2019-06-07T07:53
2019-06-07T11:53    2019-06-07T07:53
2019-06-07T13:53    2019-06-07T07:53
2019-06-07T15:53    2019-06-07T07:53
2019-06-07T17:53    2019-06-07T07:53
```

Intended Output is to create "Time.After.Dose"

```
Sample.Time          Dose.Time         Time.After.Dose
2019-06-07T08:23    2019-06-07T07:53    0.5
2019-06-07T08:53    2019-06-07T07:53    1
2019-06-07T09:23    2019-06-07T07:53    1.5
2019-06-07T09:53    2019-06-07T07:53    2
2019-06-07T10:23    2019-06-07T07:53    2.5
2019-06-07T10:53    2019-06-07T07:53    3
2019-06-07T11:53    2019-06-07T07:53    4
2019-06-07T13:53    2019-06-07T07:53    6
2019-06-07T15:53    2019-06-07T07:53    8
2019-06-07T17:53    2019-06-07T07:53    10
2019-06-07T19:50    2019-06-07T07:53    11.95
2019-06-08T07:43    2019-06-07T07:53    23.83333333
2019-06-09T07:43    2019-06-07T07:53    47.83333333
2019-06-12T07:43    2019-06-07T07:53    119.8333333
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure you could have found similar worked examples but R datetimes are a common source of confusios, so I guess I will save you the time:

```
dat <- read.table(text="Sample.Time         Dose.Time
2019-06-07T08:23    2019-06-07T07:53
2019-06-07T08:53    2019-06-07T07:53
2019-06-07T09:23    2019-06-07T07:53
2019-06-07T09:53    2019-06-07T07:53
2019-06-07T10:23    2019-06-07T07:53
2019-06-07T10:53    2019-06-07T07:53
2019-06-07T11:53    2019-06-07T07:53
2019-06-07T13:53    2019-06-07T07:53
2019-06-07T15:53    2019-06-07T07:53
2019-06-07T17:53    2019-06-07T07:53", head=TRUE)

 dat$Time.After.Dose <- difftime( as.POSIXct( dat[[1]], format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M"), 
                                  as.POSIXct( dat[[2]], format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M"), 
                                  units="min")

> dat
        Sample.Time        Dose.Time Time.After.Dose
1  2019-06-07T08:23 2019-06-07T07:53         30 mins
2  2019-06-07T08:53 2019-06-07T07:53         60 mins
3  2019-06-07T09:23 2019-06-07T07:53         90 mins
4  2019-06-07T09:53 2019-06-07T07:53        120 mins
5  2019-06-07T10:23 2019-06-07T07:53        150 mins
6  2019-06-07T10:53 2019-06-07T07:53        180 mins
7  2019-06-07T11:53 2019-06-07T07:53        240 mins
8  2019-06-07T13:53 2019-06-07T07:53        360 mins
9  2019-06-07T15:53 2019-06-07T07:53        480 mins
10 2019-06-07T17:53 2019-06-07T07:53        600 mins
```

The key points are that there is a time difference function and that the arguments to that function need to be POSIXct class and `as.POSIXct` in turn needs have the proper format string for the text values you present. Technically those columns are factor values, so I should proibably have added stringsAsFactors=FALSE at the input stage.

Answer (score 2):

My answer is similar to other answers. I want to show that after the calculation of time difference, we can use `as.double` and set the `units` argument to `hours` to get the desired output. This example also shows how to do this operation using the `data.table` package.

```
# Load packages
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)

# Create example data frame
dat <- fread("Sample.Time         Dose.Time
2019-06-07T08:23    2019-06-07T07:53
2019-06-07T08:53    2019-06-07T07:53
2019-06-07T09:23    2019-06-07T07:53
2019-06-07T09:53    2019-06-07T07:53
2019-06-07T10:23    2019-06-07T07:53
2019-06-07T10:53    2019-06-07T07:53
2019-06-07T11:53    2019-06-07T07:53
2019-06-07T13:53    2019-06-07T07:53
2019-06-07T15:53    2019-06-07T07:53
2019-06-07T17:53    2019-06-07T07:53")

# Convert to POSIXct class
dat <- dat[, lapply(.SD, function(x) ymd_hm(x))]

# See the class of each column
str(dat)
# Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':    10 obs. of  3 variables:
#   $ Sample.Time    : POSIXct, format: "2019-06-07 08:23:00" "2019-06-07 08:53:00" "2019-06-07 09:23:00" "2019-06-07 09:53:00" ...
# $ Dose.Time      : POSIXct, format: "2019-06-07 07:53:00" "2019-06-07 07:53:00" "2019-06-07 07:53:00" "2019-06-07 07:53:00" ...
# $ Time.After.Dose: num  0.5 1 1.5 2 2.5 3 4 6 8 10
# - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 

# Create a new column shows the time differences as hours
dat[, Time.After.Dose := as.double(Sample.Time - Dose.Time, units = "hours")]
print(dat)
#             Sample.Time           Dose.Time Time.After.Dose
#  1: 2019-06-07 08:23:00 2019-06-07 07:53:00             0.5
#  2: 2019-06-07 08:53:00 2019-06-07 07:53:00             1.0
#  3: 2019-06-07 09:23:00 2019-06-07 07:53:00             1.5
#  4: 2019-06-07 09:53:00 2019-06-07 07:53:00             2.0
#  5: 2019-06-07 10:23:00 2019-06-07 07:53:00             2.5
#  6: 2019-06-07 10:53:00 2019-06-07 07:53:00             3.0
#  7: 2019-06-07 11:53:00 2019-06-07 07:53:00             4.0
#  8: 2019-06-07 13:53:00 2019-06-07 07:53:00             6.0
#  9: 2019-06-07 15:53:00 2019-06-07 07:53:00             8.0
# 10: 2019-06-07 17:53:00 2019-06-07 07:53:00            10.0
```

Comment: So the - has a POSIXct method that allows specifying units? I didn't know that. And , wow, it even in the base-environment. Double-wow.

Comment: Nope. There's a `-.POSIXt` function which somehow manages to see that units argument despite `-` being a binary operator.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `lubridate` to transform your dates characters into `POSIXct` format and then perform a subtraction.

```
#The first three lines of your data
df <- data.frame(
  sample.time = c("2019-06-07T08:23","2019-06-07T08:53","2019-06-07T09:23"),
  dose.time = c("2019-06-07T07:53", "2019-06-07T07:53","2019-06-07T07:53"), stringsAsFactors = F
)

library(lubridate)

df$sample.time<-ymd_hm(df$sample.time)
df$dose.time<-ymd_hm(df$dose.time)

#Change the difference in minutes to hours and set it as a numeric value
df$Time.After.Dose <- as.numeric((df$sample.time - df$dose.time) / 60)

#          sample.time           dose.time Time.After.Dose
#1 2019-06-07 08:23:00 2019-06-07 07:53:00             0.5
#2 2019-06-07 08:53:00 2019-06-07 07:53:00             1.0
#3 2019-06-07 09:23:00 2019-06-07 07:53:00             1.5
```

Comment: Thank you, Jonathan. We need to account for date as well because sampling can occur on a different date than dosing.

Comment: This solution should work. The only thing is that it will give you the results in hours. If you wish to count difference in days and hours you could use something like: `df$Time.After.Dose_day <- floor(df$Time.After.Dose / 24)
df$Time.After.Dose_hour <- df$Time.After.Dose %% 24`